# knp-paginator-bundle install failed on symfony3

Tags: php, symfony, knppaginator

I have installed symfony 3.3 using below mention composer code.

composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition my_project_name 3.3

Now i would like to install knp-paginator-bundle , using ' composer require knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle ' , but whenever I run this command, can't get past after the message - 'Updating dependencies (including require-dev)'

Could someone guide me how to install them?

Comment: What does happen after that? Do you get a error message?

Comment: no error message, nothing 
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

Comment: I mostly use silverstripe for cms,  so i tried to install ss module using composer, they all  working fine.

Comment: the issue was with memory size, I tried with new virtual host then started the showing error message 'Cannot allocate memory ' message. when increase the memory size, was able to install them.